# Does the XML Encryption flaw affect WCF X.509 certificate-based security?

Tags: xml, wcf, encryption

A "practical attack against XML's cipher block chaining (CBC) mode" has been demonstrated:

http://www.informationweek.com/news/security/vulnerabilities/231901532

My question is this:  Does this affect WCF's X.509 certificate-based message-level security?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posed this very question to MS Support.  The Q&A is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a1e74f4b-9469-43bb-9e91-4d524bee6ceb.  Scroll to the end, where I was able to enlist the support people to specifically answer publicly.

The short answer is **NO, the technique described in the paper does NOT affect X.509 certificate-based message-level security.**

Indeed, the WCF stack is specifically protected from the attack because it is not possible to Encrypt-Only traffic.  The vulnerability affects Encrypt-Only, but does not affect Encrypted-And-Signed.  The description at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.protectionlevel.aspx describes what MS WCF allows.  WCF will not even accept Encrypted-Only traffic.

Though there seeems to be a problem with the base W3C Encryption Spec in not being tight enough, I think the real in-our-face vulnerability is in the Axis2 space - where it *is* possible to Encrypt-Only.

I do wish MS would let WCF encrypt via the AES-GCM instead of AES-CBC.  Given the success of the CBC attack, it does seem like CBC's days should be numbered in production systems.

Answer (score 2):

WCF uses XMLDSIG to encrypt their messages (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx). So, if you use WCF encryption with any block cipher in CBC-mode you will be vulnerable.

Sady, the CBC mode is the default mode for WCF (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.mode.aspx).

Comment: See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/is-the-cbc-weakness-in-xml-encryption-a-new-discovery-are-other-applications-vu.

Comment: According to the analysis [here](http://practicalcrypto.blogspot.com/2011/10/attack-of-week-xml-encryption.html), this happens because the servers respond with enough information about the issue to prove useful to the attacker. Does WCF provide this information by default as well?

Comment: Also, what about [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/XML-Encryption-Flaw-Leaves-E-Commerce-Exposed-229381.shtml)?  It states, "The process seems to be working only when AES encryption is utilized in the CBC mode, so if an RSA key or X.509 certificates are used for the codification, the attack concept is not effective."  Since the certificate is only used to exchange a key, is this irrelevant, or can this be read to say that, since the symmetric key needs to be established before being used, the attack isn't relevant?

Comment: Read the actual paper and, as near as I can tell, there would be enough data returned to the attacker and using an X.509 certificate doesn't prevent it.  Thanks for all the links that enabled me to read up on this issue.

Comment: @zimdanen, I'm researching the same question.  From reading the article and some stuff on crypto.stackexchange.com I think **all** WCF Message Encryption is comprimised.  Reflector says that **all** the algorithm-suites defined in `System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite` use CBC, not just the default AES 256 (aka Basic256) for .NET 4.  MSDN indicates .NET 4.5 (as of 11/4/2011) is unchanged here.

Comment: I note that WCF ProtectionLevel only ever can be None, Sign, EncryptAndSign, see [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.protectionlevel.aspx).  So Encrypt-without-Sign cannot be done by a .NET client using WCF.  The paper points out that a service that processed encrypt-only traffic is susceptible to the attack.  I wonder what .NET WCF does if supplied an encrypt-only SOAP message.  I also wonder whether EncryptAndSign effectively prevents the attack for Message Security (w/o transport security).